# DataBinding/DataContext in Code behind (WPF - MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So currently I am learning WPF and MVVM and I have some trouble understanding `DataContext` and `DataBinding`. My problem is that I do not understand how to access the data from code behind.

To elaborate my problem here is an example:

Let's say I have an application that should allow me to place `Rectangles` on a `Canvas`. The application consists of a window which has 3 subviews

- `Canvas` that draws the `Rectangles` using `ItemsControl` with a `ContentPresenter`
- A `View` that shows parameters (Width,Height,X,Y)
- A `ListBox` that shows me all created rectangles

I have a ViewModel for the `Rectangles` and a MainViewModel which has an `ObservableCollection<RectangleViewModel>` and saves which Rectangle is currently selected.

The three `Views`inherit the `DataContext` from the `MainWindow` which has the `MainViewModel` as `DataContext`. Binding values in the `XAML` is no problem at all.

However the user should be able to drag and resize rectangles on the `CanvasView`. For that I added `MouseEvents` to the `CanvasView.cs` which recognize that I clicked on a rectangle and an `Adorner` to show the user that he can interact.

The `Adorner` is coded in a seperate class file and handles the resize actions. The problem is that the Adorner just edits the `ContentPresenter` Item.

How can I tell the `Adorner` or any other code behind that they should edit the Rectangle in the `ObservableCollection<Rectangles>` in the `MainViewModel`? The `MouseEvent` can only retrieve the `UIElement` which has the `Rectangle` as `DataContext` so I can't tell my `MainViewModel` that a certain Rectangle is currently selected.

Should all actions take place in the `MainViewModel` (i.e. MouseEvent directs to static method in MainViewModel that edits stuff)? Do I need to 'reload' the `MainViewModel` after every change or what would be the ideal way to access the data and edit it?

I hope this kind of explains my problem. If you need a further explanation of my problem please comment down below.

Comment: The question is too broad, especially without a good [mcve] illustrating it. But, generally: all your code's interaction should be mediated by the view models, so they should already know what's currently selected. Maybe part of your problem is that you're handling mouse events in the `Canvas`, instead of the individual `Rectangle` elements. If you were doing the latter, then you'd have access to the `Rectangle.DataContext` value that is set to the individual view model instead of the `MainViewModel` object. You'll have to narrow the question to get an actual answer though.